# Angular: set cookie with http request

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to set a cookie with an initial http request?

Meaning, I would like to call a url and set cookies at the same time. Not sure how to go about this? Thank-you

**Update:** I am not doing cross domain, but sub domain in new tab.

Comment: Are you doing cross domain request?

Comment: good point, I updated question - thanks

Comment: When you say Initial HTTP Request, does it means the first HTTP request ever made by AngularJS framework (loading templates, etc) or any user triggered action? Like an API call or custom request?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies fly with the HTTP request at the moment those requests depart. So cookies must be already set prior the HTTP request, so the browser can package them.

If you just want to set a cookie prior your request, you can do so by using the `$cookies` service:

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');

  // Make your HTTP Request here //
  // $http.get('/someUrl').then(...);
}]);
```

Now, if you want those cookies being set transparently without the need to scatter `$cookies` everywhere, you should write a HTTP Interceptor and set those cookies there. You can read how to do it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (Look for Interceptors).

Once you create your interceptor, which is essentially a Factory, you can hook it up in your `.Config` stage, like this: `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');`. Then, even calls made by the AngularJS Framework will receive this cookie.

If this is not what you want, comment here and I will try to update it.